# Display all fields except the last

Tags: shell, sed, awk, solaris

I have a file as show below

```
1.2.3.4.ask
sanma.nam.sam
c.d.b.test
```

I want to remove the last field from each line, the delimiter is `.` and the number of fields are not constant.

Can anybody help me with an `awk` or `sed` to find out the solution. I can't use `perl` here.

Answer (score 26):

Both these `sed` and `awk` solutions work independent of the number of fields.

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*)\..*/\1/' file
1.2.3.4
sanma.nam
c.d.b
```

Note: `-r` is the flag for extended regexp, it could be `-E` so check with `man sed`. If your version of `sed` doesn't have a flag for this then just escape the brackets:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' file
1.2.3.4
sanma.nam
c.d.b
```

The `sed` solution is doing a greedy match up to the last `.` and capturing everything before it, it replaces the whole line with only the matched part (`n-1` fields). Use the `-i` option if you want the changes to be stored back to the files.

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{NF--; print}' file
1.2.3.4
sanma.nam
c.d.b
```

The `awk` solution just simply prints `n-1` fields, to store the changes back to the file use redirection:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."}{NF--; print}' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Comment: awesome Sudo_O , the awk solution worked . actually sed should have also worked but the -r option doesn't work with solaris sed. Solaris has pretty old sed and awk. anyways thanks for the really fast help

Comment: Yes I thought that just after I posted and updated my answer, see the edit on sed and extended regexp :) also please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: +1 for the correct solution, and there's the sed-like GNU awk alternative `gawk '{print gensub(/(.*)\..*/,"\\1","")}'` just for completeness.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Thanks for showing both `sed` and `awk` solutions.

Comment: +1. If there are no empty lines in the input, the awk script can be reduced to `NF--`, e.g. `awk NF-- FS=. OFS=.`.

Comment: To also work with empty lines an extra check is needed `NF==0 || NF--`.

Comment: @thor got to love `awk` ;)

Comment: How to print the fields with `awk` but using comma as field separator?

Comment: in Mac I could only make it work with `$NF=""`. `print` was not updated with `NF--`

Answer (score 9):

Reverse, cut, reverse back.

```
rev file | cut -d. -f2- | rev >newfile
```

Or, replace from last dot to end with nothing:

```
sed 's/\.[^.]*$//' file >newfile
```

The regex `[^.]` matches one character which is not dot (or newline). You need to exclude the dot because the repetition operator `*` is "greedy"; it will select the leftmost, longest possible match.

Comment: sorry to say but i dont have rev command in solaris . it works in linux

Comment: If you have Perl you can reimplement it easily. `perl -lpe '$_=reverse' filename`

Answer (score 3):

With `cut` on the reversed string

```
cat youFile | rev |cut -d "." -f 2- | rev
```

Comment: Beware the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the "." use below:

```
awk '{gsub(/[^\.]*$/,"");print}' your_file
```

Comment: this removes the "." filed also

Comment: The `awk` solutions still leaves the last `.`

Comment: @sudo....i guess you can see the comment above by the OP .he says that my first soltion removes the last ".".And this is the reason why i had to change it to preserve the last "."