# awk Getting ALL line but last field with the delimiters

Tags: bash, awk

I have to make a one-liner that renames all files in the current directory
that end in ".hola" to ".txt".

For example:

`sample.hola and name.hi.hola` will be renamed to `sample.txt` and `name.hi.txt` respectively

I was thinking about something like:

`ls -1 *.hola | awk '{NF="";print "$0.hola $0.txt"}'` (*)

And then passing the stdin to `xargs mv -T` with a `|`

But the output of (*) for the example would be `sample` and `name hi`.

How do I get the output `name.hi` for `name.hi.hola` using `awk`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857836/display-all-fields-except-the-last. Then try `echo name.hi.hola | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=".";FS="."} {NF--;print}'`. You can adapt this to your example. Mark Reed's answer is appropriate for the problem you intend to solve.

Comment: Note that modifying `NF` like that only works in GNU awk, not BSD/MacOS awk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you want to involve awk in this?

```
$ for f in *.hola; do echo mv "$f" "${f%hola}txt"; done
mv name.hi.hola name.hi.txt
mv sample.hola sample.txt
```

Remove the `echo` when you're happy with the output.

Comment: I wanted the `awk` because it was for a homework, but now that i see your solution I didnt know that you can do `${f%hola}.txt` to substitute the "hola". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, for your specific problem, I recommend the `rename` command. Depending on the version on your system, you can do either `rename -s .hola .txt *.hola`, or `rename 's/\.hola$/.txt/' *.hola`.

Also, you shouldn't use `ls` to get filenames. When you run `ls *.hola`, the *shell* expands `*.hola` to a list of all the filenames matching that pattern, and `ls` is just a glorified `echo` at that point. You can get the same result using e.g. `printf '%s\n' *.hola` without running any program outside the shell.

And your `awk` is missing any attempt to remove the `.hola`. If you have GNU awk, you can do something like this:

```
awk -F. '{old=$0; NF-=1; new=$0".txt"; print old" "new}'
```

That won't work on BSD/MacOS `awk`. In that case you can do something like this:

```
awk -F. '{
  old=$0; new=$1; 
  for (i=2;i<NF;++i) { new=new"."$i }; 
  print old" "new".txt"; }'
```

Either way, I'm sure @EdMorton probably has a better `awk`-based solution.

Comment: Im in GNU and i tried your `awk` solution and I've got the same output, the dots in the input dissapear in `new`. I didnt knew about the `rename` comand, I think I'll have to investigate more. If I use `ls -1 *.hola` it will list all in column.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' *.hola` also outputs in a column

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Simple and straightforward:

```
for file in *.hola; do mv "$file" "${file/%hola/txt}"; done
```

Comment: mmmm I think I should learn more about the `bash` commandline. I did not knowthat `${file/%hola/text}` will replace those "hola's". I think that the solution was using `awk` because it was for a homework about it.