# sed: replace from the last occurrence of "-" till EOL

Tags: regex, sed

## My problem

I have a file with items, one per line. The item contains at least one dash, and I would like to remove the last dash and the words that follow. For example:

```
item asdkalqndla-asdnkfsv-324we-blueray
item asda-vbght564e-dfg-redapple
item gefdsc-fgy-543-5trr-floatingvanilla
```

Should give:

```
item asdkalqndla-asdnkfsv-324we
item asda-vbght564e-dfg
item gefdsc-fgy-543-5trr
```

## What have I tried

```
sed 's/\-.*$//' lines.txt
```

Which gives

```
item asdkalqndla
item asda
item gefdsc
```

Because the regex is greedy, and consumes everything from the first dash onwards.

## My question

**How can I remove all characters from the last `-` in a string till EOL?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display all fields except the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857836/display-all-fields-except-the-last)

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{sub(/-[^-]*$/,""); print}' file
item asdkalqndla-asdnkfsv-324we
item asda-vbght564e-dfg
item gefdsc-fgy-543-5trr
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple negation using `^\-` solved the problem:

```
$ sed 's/\-[^\-]*$//' lines.txt
item asdkalqndla-asdnkfsv-324we
item asda-vbght564e-dfg
item gefdsc-fgy-543-5trr
```

This way, sed replaces a dash followed by anything-but-dash till the end of the line.

Comment: You don't need to escape dashes.

Answer (score 2):

Following simple `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F"-" 'NF{NF=(NF-1)} 1' OFS="-"   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
item asdkalqndla-asdnkfsv-324we
item asda-vbght564e-dfg
item gefdsc-fgy-543-5trr
```

***Explanation:*** 
`-F"-"`: Making field separator as `-` for each line for Input_file.

`NF{NF=(NF-1)}`: `awk` has out of the box `NF` variable which has number of fields for any line, since we don't text after last occurrence of `-` and field separator is `-`, by mentioning `NF`, we are checking if a line is NOT EMPTY. decrementing the number of field's value with `1` so that we will NOT get the last field.

`1`: `awk` works on method of `condition` then `action` so making condition part TRUE here by mentioning 1 here and not mentioning any action here so by default print of current line will happen.

`OFS="-"`: Making `OFS` output field separator as `"-"` here so that `-` will come in output.

***EDIT:*** Shorter versions of decrementing `NF` too as follows.

```
awk -F"-" 'NF{NF-=1} 1' OFS="-"  Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F"-" 'NF{NF--} 1' OFS="-"  Input_file
```

Comment: writing `NF--` is shorter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, then I could use `NF-=1` too I think :)

Comment: I don't think you can assign a negative value to NF. That's a problem. If the line has zero field, it produces an error. Conclusion it's better to write: `NF&&NF--`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, mentioned it now, thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)-.*/\1/' file
```

Used greed to find the last `-` and replace the whole line with what came before it.